# Infinite force at nonzero distance

Tags: forces, distance

Why is that all of the four fundamental forces in nature approach +/- infinity as the Euclidan distance between the two point-like objects approaches zero? Is there any explanation for that or "this is just how nature works"?

Comment: They do not become infinitely large as the separation **approaches** zero. They just become larger and larger. The "sizes" of the objects also need to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that as the Euclidian distance decreases the force between suppose charged particles increases, that is $F=\frac{k}{r^2}$. But the objects like protons themselves have a 'size' so that limits the force to actually go to infinity. A better explanation is that as protons become *very* close( about $10^{-15}m$) the strong nuclear force of attraction dominated over the electric repulsion so the protons can fuse.

In other concepts, we can also trace the expansion of the universe backwards in time and find that there should have been a point where all the mass was concentrated in zero volume giving rise to infinity density, a *singularity*. The laws of Physics under most theories collapse there and we have to modify our understanding to understand *those* situations better(e.g. using String Theory) and we are still learning and researching on this.

Comment: Since the question is about point-like objects composite particles, such as protons are trivially an incorrect approach in answering my question. However, you mentioned the strong nuclear force, which also creates an equilibrial distance between the gluons composing the protons beyond wich it also starts to repell. And as $r$ goes to 0, the force also goes to $\infty$.

Comment: That is correct, since there are no such "physical" true point like objects owing to the uncertainty in quantum mechanics we can account for the infinite force( technically not possible for physical objects but certainly true for point like objects which are non existent )

Comment: When one sketches out the Scrödinger equation or Dirac equation of a system it always contains potentials for two-body interactions between point-like objects. It is not an approximation, since the uncertainty arises from the behaviour of the wave-function which is the result of the former equation. Maybe my question wasn't quantum-mechanics compatible, so a more precise question would be "Why do all potential functions of the four fundamental forces approach $\infty$ as $r$ approaches $0$ and why don't they diverge sooner?".

Comment: You may point out that they don't diverge sooner as the origin of their respective fields according to Quantum Field theory begins at the point particle, hence only as the distance between the points approaches zero thus the force approaches infinity.